# Javascript ondbclick

Tags: javascript, events

I've got a table. I want its every "td" to call an event when double-clicked.
So,

```
var cell = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

cell.ondblclick = function() {
alert('You clicked me!');
};
```

I understand it like "When you click on a cell you get the alert message "You clicked me!" But it doesn't work for some reason.

var cell exists (checked by console)
Please guys help to solve the issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a HTMLCollection. You can not add events to a live HTMLCollection. You need to add the event to each element of the collection.

```js
var cell = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
  cell[i].ondblclick = function() {
    alert("clicked");
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A better way [in most cases] is to add one click to a parent and use event delegation instead of adding tons of events to the page.

```js
var myTbody = document.querySelector(".myTable tbody");
myTbody.addEventListener("dblclick", function(evt) {
  var elem = evt.target;
  if (elem.tagName === "TD") {
    alert(elem.textContent);
  }
});
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
    cells[i].ondblclick = function() {
       alert('You clicked me!');
    };
}
```